# Указатели как параметры функции, динамические массивы (С++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, указатели, динамические-массивы

Моя задача:

> Объявите указатель на массив типа double и предложите пользователю выбрать его размер. Далее напишите четыре функции: первая должна выделить память для массива, вторая – заполнить ячейки данными, третья – показать данные на экран, четвертая – освободить занимаемую память. Программа должна предлагать пользователю продолжать работу (создавать новые динамические массивы ) или выйти из программы.

Не работает мой код, где ошибки и проблемы?

Собственно,код:

```
// pointers.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

double giveTheMemory(double *Array, int size);
void fillUpTheArray(double *Array, int size);
void ShowTheData(double *Array, int size);
void clearTheMemory(double *Array);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    double *myArray;
    char checkuser;
    do
    {
        int sizeOfArray = 0;
        cout << "Vvedite razmer massiva:" << endl;
        cin >> sizeOfArray;

        giveTheMemory(myArray, sizeOfArray);
        fillUpTheArray(myArray, sizeOfArray);
        ShowTheData(myArray, sizeOfArray);
        clearTheMemory(myArray);

        cout << "Videlyat novii massiv(y\n)?" << endl;
        cin >> checkuser;
    } while (checkuser != 'n');

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}

double giveTheMemory(double *Array, int size)
{
    Array = new double[size];
    return Array;
}
void fillUpTheArray(double *Array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Array[i] = i + 1;
    }
}
void ShowTheData(double *Array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << Array[i] << ' ';
    }
}
void clearTheMemory(double *Array)
{
    delete[] Array;
}
```

Comment: Как минимум, у вас ошибка компиляции в строке `return Array;` — вы должны возвращать значение типа `double`, а пытаетесь вместо этого вернуть указатель этого типа.

Comment: @Arhad сомневался в этой функции, так как не уверен, что нужно вообще возвращать что-то

Comment: Как правильно сделать?

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich, если кратко, то вероятнее всего ты хочешь возвращать из giveTheMemory `double *`, а не передавать в неё указатель на указатель; и соответственно вызывать её как-то так: `myArray = giveTheMemory(sizeOfArray);`

Comment: @Fat-Zer а что по поводу первого параметра в этой функции, и что именно она должна возвращать?

Comment: Artem Aleksandrovich  выделит память с таким размером и вернет указатель на этот массив

Comment: А чтобы функция вернула указатель, мне нужно так определить функцию : double *giveTheMemory(double *Array, int size) ?

Comment: только  как подсказал  Fat-Zer  - без первого аргумента

Comment: А разве указатель myArray будет доступен в функции?

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich, нет, но в функции ты его и не используешь.

Comment: Почему? Я пишу double *myArray = new double[size] в функции

Comment: и вроде работает.просто не понимаю.я в параметрах указатель не задавал,но все работает если так написать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double giveTheMemory(double *Array, int size)
{
    Array = new double[size];
    return Array;
}
```

либо замените на

```
void giveTheMemory(double*& Array, int size)
{
    Array = new double[size];
}
```

и вызывайте как

```
giveTheMemory(myArray, sizeOfArray);
```

либо на

```
double* giveTheMemory(int size)
{
    return new double[size];
}
```

и вызывайте как

```
myArray = giveTheMemory(sizeOfArray);
```

Comment: что значит double*& Array ?

Comment: Ссылка на указатель на `double`. Раз у нас С++, лучше использовать передачу по ссылке, чем по указателю.